# netsh and cmd profiles differ from taskbar

Tags: cmd.exe, administrator, netsh

I'm trying to figure out how to reconcile the wlan profiles I can show in cmd window vs. what my taskbar shows. They are different.

Does the task bar wifi show more RECENT wifi connections vs. the cmd prompt? I'm curious b/c sometimes my ISP will quit working and ahem I MAY have to borrow my neighbor's wifi.

Yes, I did research this for a bit, but nothing was helpful. thx

Comment: If you're talking about command `netsh wlan show profiles` then that shows only those "saved" WLAN profiles which you are connected and not all Wi-Fi SSIDs that are being broadcast or whatever. So the `netsh wlan show profiles` and what you see from the GUI taskbar for all network SSIDs the WLAN sees are not the same. Please clarify what specific `netsh` command you are running.

Comment: @IT Snuggles - that is the precise command - "netsh wlan show profiles" from Administrator cmd. So, how do I delete the saved profiles and save new SSID's that I come up to?

Comment: @IT Snuggles - DOOOOD, you are the man!!! Many thx!. I've had this laptop for almost a year, so I'm assuming that the profiles that were on my laptop were from when I opened and booted up initially.

Comment: @IT Snuggles - I think I just "greened" it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **how do I delete the saved profiles and save new SSID's**

### Delete Wi-Fi Profile

```
NETSH WLAN DELETE PROFILE NAME="<WLAN Profile Name>"
```

<sub>[example source](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3507-delete-wireless-network-profile-windows-10-a.html)</sub>

---

### Connect to Wi-Fi SSID

```
NETSH WLAN CONNECT SSID=<SSID> NAME=<WLAN Profile Name>
```

<sub>[example source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163737/how-to-connect-to-a-wifi-using-cmd-only)</sub>

---

### Add Wi-Fi Profile with Passphrase

> So you already know `netsh wlan`
>
> If you enter it you get a list of possible commands. One is `add`.
>
> If you enter `netsh wlan add` you get another list of possible
>   subcommands. One is `profile`.
>
> If you enter `netsh wlan add profile` you get a detailed explanation
>   about all its possible parameters. One needed parameter is a XML file
>   containing the profile informations.
>
> So how to get such an XML file? Go back to `netsh wlan` and study the
>   keywords. There is `export`.
>
> If you enter `netsh wlan export` you get another list of possible
>   subcommands. One is `profile`. It creates an XML in your local
>   directory containing the needed informations for your current WiFi
>   connection.
>
> If you like to get the password in clear text, you'll also have to add
>   the parameter `key=clear`. Make the whole command becoming
>
> ```
> netsh wlan export profile key=clear
> ```
>
> Here is an example which already contains the needed placeholders
>
> > ```
> > <?xml version="1.0"?>
> > <WLANProfile xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1">
> >  <name>{SSID}</name>
> >  <SSIDConfig>
> >      <SSID>
> >          <name>{SSID}</name>
> >      </SSID>
> >  </SSIDConfig>
> >  <connectionType>ESS</connectionType>
> >  <connectionMode>auto</connectionMode>
> >  <MSM>
> >      <security>
> >          <authEncryption>
> >              <authentication>WPA2PSK</authentication>
> >              <encryption>AES</encryption>
> >              <useOneX>false</useOneX>
> >          </authEncryption>
> >          <sharedKey>
> >              <keyType>passPhrase</keyType>
> >              <protected>false</protected>
> >              <keyMaterial>{password}</keyMaterial>
> >          </sharedKey>
> >      </security>
> >  </MSM>
> >  <MacRandomization xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v3">
> >      <enableRandomization>false</enableRandomization>
> >  </MacRandomization>
> > </WLANProfile>
> > ```
>
> Simply replace the keywords `{SSID}` (occurs two times) and
>   `{password}` with the desired values and import that file by calling
>
> ```
> netsh wlan add profile filename="myProfile.xml"
> ```
>
> <sub>[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163737/how-to-connect-to-a-wifi-using-cmd-only)</sub>

---

### Further Resources

- [Netsh Commands for Wireless Local Area Network (WLAN) in Windows~](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755301(v=ws.10).aspx#bkmk_wlanAddProfile)
- [Create wireless profile in command line](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6a2def2e-8663-4c19-8fba-c2c4c3f0eb57/create-wireless-profile-in-command-line?forum=w7itpronetworking)